FreeCAD/OpenFOAM vs Paid CFD Software
I am a mechanical engineer who is dipping his toes in CFD for a work project, where we have an array of axial fans in a tower and we're trying to optimise the airflow (its actually two towers facing each other, recirculating a flow of high-velocity air between them).
I found FreeCAD with its CfdOF plugin and was using that earlier in the project to analyse both the box design and the arrangement of the fan arrays. I was able to get some idea of the resultant turbulence of various fan arrangements (see below Surface LIC) (we were aiming for the most laminar flow we could get, with minimal stagnant zones), however I couldn't get anything meaningful out of modelling the boxes, so I just went back to physical iterative testing. after roughly 20 iterations and 700 measurements, I arrived at the design below.
Now the management is considering paid CFD software to further improve the design. We have set up a demonstration with SimScale, and will also look at other packages.
My feeling is that the free software I've been using isn't the limiting factor, I am. I suspect that if I was better at CFD I could get the results I need from FreeCAD. I also suspect that after the iterative testing I've already done, further gains would be somewhat limited.
My question is: will a paid software package help me in this case? Does paid software have more user-friendliness that will help me to improve my CFD model to get useful results out of it?
Followup question: What are some recommendations of good CFD packages? Is SimScale any good? We use Solidworks, is the Simulation add-on for that any good?



Phoenics by Cham (https://www.cham.co.uk/phoenics.php) is one commercial package which has been used for many years.
the advantage is the level of support - they have engineers who will work with you unlike the free codes where you rely on people giving of free time.

I have no opinion on FreeCAD but OpenFOAM is widely used in the automotive industry, including OEMs, some tier 1 suppliers, and F1 racing teams.
https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam/60810-industries-using-openfoam.html
https://www.reddit.com/r/F1Technical/comments/rwyqdg/cfd_software_used_by_f1_teams/
As such I doubt it is the tool that is directly the problem.

I've heard that as well, and I don't doubt the power of OpenFOAM. However my experience with various mechanical CAD packages has taught me that you are not paying for computational accuracy/quality so much as refinement, depth of features and the user-friendly interface.
